# solve equations using multiple values of x

Tags: python

I need help on the fallowing: Lets say you ask the user for an ecuation it can be anything, for illustrating this example lets the the user choose this one:

x**5+3, and he also needs to assign any value of x, so it will look like this:
write the equation:
write the value of x you want to calculate:

my question is: how can you modify the x in the equation the user gave first to assign the value he wants to calculate?? in other worlds how can I make python calculate x**5+2, for x= any input value??

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking for, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the user to enter an equation with variables and the value for the variable. And you want your code to evaluate the user input equation with user input value for the variable in the equation. Sounds like a candidate for [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
In [185]: equation = 'x ** 5 + 2'
In [186]: x = 3
In [187]: eval(equation)
Out[187]: 245
```

Another example:

```
In [188]: equation = '(x + 99) * 2'
In [189]: x = 1
In [190]: eval(equation)
Out[190]: 200
```

Since in the above demonstration, `equation` is a string, it might as well be a user input. When you ask the user to input for the equation, store it in a variable (variable `equation` here). Then when you ask them for a value for the variables in the equation, cast it to `int` and just do a `eval(equation)` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to decipher, but if I understand correctly, you're talking about writing a function. Try the following:

```
def f(x):
    return x**5 + 2
```

And you may use the function for any value of x, e.g., `f(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is relativity easily to do if you look up each piece of the puzzle (or coding problem in this case).

First you need user input:

```
x_string = input("Enter an x value: ")
```

Then you need to convert the input String into an integer:

```
x = int(x_string)
```

Finally you need to calculate the value and print it out:

```
results = x**5 + 2
print results
```

You seem to be new to Python, so I **highly** recommend looking up some tutorials (like [this one](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SimplePrograms)).